# Angular localstorage Override issue

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, local-storage

I am storing my access-Token in my local storage for the authentication purpose of the system.
If User-A logs in, his access-token is getting set in Local-storage. All fine till here. But on same time, if another tab of same projects open and User-B logs in, his access-token is getting written in local-storage and its overriding the local-storage of the User-A. If I reload the User-A tab, its content are changing to User B content.

Comment: This is default browser behaviour, you could make the access-token unique by prefixing it with the username like: `userA-access-token` and `userB-access-token`. An alternative is to use incognito or another browser for the second user.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, we can use incognito and another browser. But have to make it feasible for users who don't know this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an `uniqueKey` to tell users apart. For real applications this sould be more unique of, like UUID.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  key: string = 'token';
  myItem: string;
  uniqueKey: number;
  localStorageParam: any;

  constructor() {
    this.uniqueKey = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000);
    localStorage.setItem(this.key + '_' + this.uniqueKey, 'Some Value');
    this.localStorageParam = localStorage;
    this.myItem = localStorage.getItem(this.key);
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-localstorage-fz9na6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Other option would be to use sessionStorage. Each user would have it's own session and session data, downside would be of course you lose that session data when session ends (i.e user logs out, closes the tab etc.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Thank you so much. Session storage helped me out on this issue.

Comment: How are you going to retrieve the token value after refreshing when the name is random?

Comment: That wasn't a concern of OP's question - he just wanted to avoid different sessions overwriting same key. If you don't have something else keeping your sessiondata (like a backend for example) then I guess you can't. But like I said, sessionStorage is a better alternative for this case and refreshing doesn't flush sessionsStorage.